# Allow a specific api gateway service to assume a role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am deploying an API Gateway and its respective role in Cloudformation. I would like only the newly created API Gateway to be able to assume the newly created role -- not any API Gateway.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  ApiGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      Name: my_api_gateway
      ProtocolType: HTTP
  ApiGatewayRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: my_api_gateway_role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: apigateway.amazonaws.com ### what should I update this to be? 
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
```

Can I use the ARN of my_api_gateway as the value for ApiGatewayRole.Properties.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement.Principal.Service? I tried accessing that with `ApiGatewayHttpApi.Arn`, but got an error:

```
Requested attribute Arn does not exist in schema for AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, resource ARNs are currently not supported for the Principal field of a trust policy (or AssumeRolePolicyDocument), except for Role ARNs. For that reason, you cannot limit the assumption of your role to a specific API Gateway instance that you create.